# jquery uncaught typeerror object has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and javascript in general and am having trouble figuring out the difference between these two code sets.  This code works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.poem-stanza').addClass('highlight');
});
```

and this code does not

```
function x() {
    $('div.poem-stanza').addclass('highlight');
}

$(document).ready(x);
```

giving the error:
`Uncaught Typeerror: Object #<Object> has no method 'addclass'`

Is there something wrong with my function declaration?  BTW, the non-working example comes straight from "Learning JQuery, Third Edition" book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addclass` should be `addClass` in your second snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is case sensitive. The correct method is `.addClass()`, not `.addclass`.